# Jquery калькулятор расчета стоимости с использыванием Bootstrap Multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка когда выбираю больше одного пользователя в поле таланты не подгружаются данные других пользователей, а так же в таблице не добавляются новые пользователи.

```js
$(function() {
  var selectUser,
    selectPrice,
    selectWorks,
    selectUslug,
    sum = 0,
    users = {
      "Вася": {
        name: "Вася",
        age: 15
      },
      "Игорь": {
        name: "Игорь",
        age: 17
      },
      "Маша": {
        name: "Маша",
        age: 19
      }

    },
    Talents = {
      "Вася": {
        "Спеть": "Спеть",
        "Сыграть на гитаре": "Сыграть на гитаре",
      },
      "Игорь": {
        "Рассказать анекдот": "Рассказать анекдот",
        "Сыграть на трубе": "Сыграть на трубе",

      },
      "Маша": {
        "Сыграть на рояле": "Сыграть на рояле",
        "Танец": "Танец"
      }

    },
    songs = {
      "Спеть": {
        533: "Калинка",
        204: "Катюша"
      }
    },

    musics = {
      "Сыграть на гитаре": {
        540: "Цыганочка",
        188: "Кузнечик"
      },
      "Сыграть на трубе": {
        540: "Весёлинькая",
        188: "Маленькая строна"
      },

      "Сыграть на рояле": {
        350: "Луная соната",
        220: "Шопен"
      },

    },

    StandUp = {
      "Рассказать анекдот": {
        800: "Про жизнь",
        204: "Вовочка"
      }
    },

    dance = {
      "Танец": {
        350: "Яблоко",
        230: "Хоровод"
      }
    };

  function insertUsers() {
    var html = '',
      user;

    for (user in users) {

      html += '<option value="' + user + '" data-user="' + user + '">' + user + '</option>';
    }
    $('#select-user').append(html);


  }

  function changeDivice() {
    selectUser = $('#calc option:checked').filter(':checked').data('user');

    insertTalents();
    recalc();
    changeTable();
    changeWork();
  }

  function insertTalents() {
    var html = '<option selected>Выберите Талант</option>',
      price;
    for (price in Talents[selectUser]) {
      html += '<option  data-price="' + price + '">' + Talents[selectUser][price] + '</option>';
    }
    $('#type-work').html(html);
  }

  function insertService() {
    var html = '<option selected>Выберите Репертуар</option>',

      price;

    for (price in songs[selectWorks]) {
      html += '<option data-price="' + price + '">' + songs[selectWorks][price] + ' ' + price + ' грн.</option>';

    }
    for (price in musics[selectWorks]) {
      html += '<option data-price="' + price + '">' + musics[selectWorks][price] + ' ' + price + ' грн.</option>';

    }
    for (price in StandUp[selectWorks]) {
      html += '<option data-price="' + price + '">' + StandUp[selectWorks][price] + ' ' + price + ' грн.</option>';

    }
    for (price in dance[selectWorks]) {
      html += '<option data-price="' + price + '">' + dance[selectWorks][price] + ' ' + price + ' грн.</option>';

    }
    $('#type-uslg').html(html);


  }


  function changeWork() {
    sum = selectWork = 0;

    selectWorks = $('#type-work option').filter(':selected').data('price');
    insertService();
    changeTable();
    recalc();
  }

  function changeService() {
    sum = selectWork = 0;
    selectUslug = $('#type-uslg option').filter(':selected').data('price');

    recalc();
  }

  function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
  }

  function recalc() {
    selectPrice = isNumeric(selectPrice) ? selectPrice : 0;
    selectUslug = isNumeric(selectUslug) ? selectUslug : 0;
    selectWorks = isNumeric(selectWorks) ? selectWorks : selectWorks;

    sum = +selectUslug;
    changeTable();
  }

  function changeTable() {
    $('.select-user').text(selectUser);
    $('.type-uslg').text(selectUslug + ' грн.');
    $('.sum').text(sum + ' грн.');
    if ($('#type-work').val() === "Выберите Талант") {
      $('.type-work').text('Выбирете пожалуйста Талант!');

    } else {
      $('.type-work').text(selectWorks);
    }
  }

  insertUsers();

  $('#select-user').multiselect({
    numberDisplayed: 3,
    buttonWidth: 'auto',
    nonSelectedText: 'Выберите пользователя',
    disableIfEmpty: false,
    allSelectedText: false,

    onChange: function(selectDivice, checked, select) {

      changeDivice();

    },


  });

  $('#type-work').change(function() {
    changeWork();
  });
  $('#type-uslg').change(function() {
    changeService();
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Калькулятор</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />
  <style>
    .calc {
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
    
    .table {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>



  <br /><br />
  <div class="container calc">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="calc">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="select-user">Выберите пользователя</label>
            <select id="select-user" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">

            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" id="type-work-div">
            <label for="type-work">Таланты</label>
            <select id="type-work" class="form-control">

            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="type-uslg">Выберете Репертуар</label>
            <select id="type-uslg" class="form-control">
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Наименование</th>
              <th>Цена</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Пользователь</td>
              <td class="select-user">-</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Талант</td>
              <td class="type-work">-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Репертуар</td>
              <td class="type-uslg">-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Примерная стоимость</td>
              <td class="sum">-</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что Вы рассматриваете только одного (первого) юзера:

```
selectUser = $('#calc option:checked').filter(':checked').data('user');
...
for (price in Talents[selectUser]) {
```

---

```
var selectedUsers,
  ...

selectedUsers = $('#select-user :checked').map(function() { return this.value; } ).get();


function insertTalents() {
  var html = '<option selected>Выберите Талант</option>';
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedUsers.length; i++) {
    for (talent in Talents[selectedUsers[i]]) {
      html += '<option  data-price="' + talent + '">' + Talents[selectedUsers[i]][talent] + '</option>';
    }
  }
  $('#type-work').html(html);
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @TrypoPhobia Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: А можете еще подсказать, пожалуйста, если есть время ... Я переделал переменную selectUser на selectUser = $('#select-user :checked').map(function() { 
return this.value; }
).get().join(); теперь второй список требует массивы с таким именем например "Вася,Петя
,Маша":{ 
"Спеть" : "Спеть","Сыграть на гитаре" : "Сыграть на гитаре",и
тд}"Вася,Петя
":{ 
"Спеть" : "Спеть","Сыграть на гитаре" : "Сыграть на гитаре",и
тд}.

Comment: @TrypoPhobia добавил

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ ВАМ СПАСИБО !!!!!!!!!!!!!!